# How to make pyreverse work when system can see pylint

Tags: python, windows, pylint, pyreverse

I have installed pylint in my system. I use python 3.6. When I call pylint from python command, I can see pylint. But when I try to call pyreverse, because I want to use it to create dot files, the system does not recognize the pyreverse command.

```
>>>python
>>>pylint
>>>pyreverse 
Not recognized as an internal command.
```

Please, how do I make the windows 7 system to see and call pyreverse. I need to use it for my work to create dot files.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
pipenv install pylint
pipenv shell
pyreverse --help
```

The magic is that pipenv does a somewhat better job of reloading PATHs to entrypoint commands than other ways to interact with environments.

Pipx would work too.